# 408s and Request Issues on specific sites and devices

Tags: domain-name-system, wifi, http-status-code-408

TLDR; wired desktop works, wired laptop cant load some sites, mobile phone not working on wifi with same sites as laptop. Noticing 408 and request generation issues but cant pinpoint what/why

Hello, I am running into a very strange issue I can not find a resolution for. Last week or so I had some power/internet outages (this was local neighborhood area and may not even be related but worth noting). Afterwards noticed some issues with connectivity on certain devices to certain websites and apps etc.

At first I thought this was just my wifi connected devices as my work laptop and cell were affected but realized my desktop was not running into these issues. Infinite load-wheel, webpages not coming up, etc. I moved to replace my router thinking it was an issue and even wiring my laptop, just as my desktop is, but still getting the same issues.

Now for the weird specifics, only certain websites are issues but all work on my desktop but not on my now wired laptop or wifi-connected phone. If I refresh a few times on my laptop some may work, if I move my phone from wifi to cell service, it will work. Desktop, not problems at all.

For example, I use Okta for my companies SSO. Desktop again, no problems. Laptop, need to refresh a few times if it ever works and noticing I am getting caught up on generating requests, per devtools. I also noticed attempts to pull docker images or snapd (laptop is Kubuntu) I am met with 408s, but I can go to dockerhub no problem. I attempt this on my desktop, no issues.

I've tried: cookies clear, re-installing chrome, purging all files and caches, dns flushes, different browsers, different routers, different cables

I am at a loss, any ideas? thank you in advance

Comment: Learned quite a bit about the issue since then, looking like im getting a tremendous amount of TCP ACK Issues, out of orders, Retransmissions in requests to things like okta, docker, zoom and more. Completely random and again my desktop on the same LAN does not appear to suffer from this. Laptop, also wired, and some mobile apps. Noticed getting ICMP Destination Unreachable Fragment Needed trying to hit the hop after my router (modem? building network?) in my pcaps when noticing not being able to connect to the above mention services